# CSS and HTML table - spacing/padding/border issue (not sure which)

Tags: html, css, padding, css-tables, spacing

I'm pretty new to this and I've tried to search for a post that answers it but every suggestion I've found seems to have no effect whatsoever.

Basically I've got a table in HTML - 2 rows, first row has just one cell (a heading) and second row has 3 cells.  I want there to be a thin border separating the three cells in row 2

---

Heading

1 | 2 | 3

---

Like that.  I've basically got it, but the 2 is flush against the line on it's left, and I want some spacing there.

I've tried:

**cellspacing:10px (in the td tag)

border-right-padding:10px

border-spacing:10px**

None seem to be the one I want...

I have manually sized the width of the cells, the top is 600px, the three below are 200px each.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you setup jsfiddle with existing code?

Comment: Why are you (very probably) using a table for layout purpose and not `display: table` and `table-cell` in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

you can use selector to select text-align & draw td borders.
http://jsfiddle.net/A85rn/

```
tr td {text-align:center;border-left:solid;border-right:solid;width:2em;}
tr td:first-of-type {text-align:left;border:none}
tr td:last-of-type {text-align:right;border:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming markup like

```
<table class=foo>
    <tr><th colspan=3>Heading
    <tr><td>1<td>2<td>3
</table>
```

To set the borders, you can set a right border on the first two `td` elements. To set spacing between the borders and the cell contents, set horizontal padding on the `td` elements; it seems natural to set both left and right padding (symmetrically), but you can tune this as desired. Example style sheet:

```
.foo td { 
    padding: 0 0.3em;
    border-right: solid 1px;
}
.foo td:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xTvGW/)